# Using a target size (torch.Size([80670, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([80670]))

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I want to implement GCN with my own dataset (from Pytorch geometric tutorial). I copied my notebook below.
It is working when I use the original implementation, However, if I want to use custom data then it gives the below error:

[My notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-UyUTsZ4YEwfy1qLmqU6JKFbySYVF_OD?usp=sharing)

[Original implementation](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14OvFnAXggxB8vM4e8vSURUp1TaKnovzX?usp=sharing)

I used [Load CSV](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/examples/hetero/load_csv.py) from pyG and tried to incorporate it into their GCN implementation. I know in the original implementation they used the same dataset but I want to try with custom data (load datasets for later).

Using a target size (torch.Size([80670, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([80670])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.

The problem arises:
Print (data)

```
HeteroData(
  movie={ x=[9742, 404] },
  user={ num_nodes=610 },
  (user, rates, movie)={
    edge_index=[2, 100836],
    edge_label=[100836] # mine is edge_label=[100836,1]
  }
)
```

I don't know how to make edge_label=[100836,1] to edge_label=[100836] which will hopefully solve the issue.

Looking forward to the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `edge_label = edge_label.squeeze()`

it will remove the extra dimension